# When North Carolina is not equal to North Carolina

Tags: php, arrays, character-encoding, associative-array

This has been boggling my mind. I have a form on a site with a input for state. To make selection easier, I provided a dropdown selection of states' names copied from the internet, formatted with a quick Python script, using a datalist element. I originally noticed some Â characters appearing before whitespaces, but that was easily fixed with encoding headers set to UTF-8. Now, I'm trying to replace the list of state names with their abbreviations for database storage, using an array of the form ["alabama" => "al", "alaska" => "ak" ...], but the names aren't matching. Here's some code as an example, which I have run for the output shown. Assume the state 'North Carolina' was selected from the dropdown, and self::$data['state'] is fetched from said dropdown, and therefore holds the value 'North Carolina'.

```
echo self::$data['state']."\n";              // Prints stored state value
$s = strtolower(self::$data['state']);       // Stores it lowercase as $s
echo "Observe: ".$s."\n";                    // Prints it, as the dropdown value
echo "Expect:  ".array_flip($states)['nc']."\n"; // Prints the north carolina key
echo "Observed matches expected: ";
if (isset($states[$s])) {                    // If north carolina is an array key
    echo 'true';                             //   print true
} else {                                     // Otherwise
    echo 'false';                            //   print false
}
```

I am checking if the state name, from the input (`self::$data['state']`) is a key in the array. Because I need to get the key name from the array, coded as `'north carolina' => 'nc'`, I am using `array_flip()` to flip the keys and values. Because the dropdown for the input has first letters capitalized, and the array is in all lowercase, I am using `strtolower()` to get the input value in all lowercase.

Now here's the fun part. Here's the output, copied and pasted directly from the browser:

```
North Carolina
Observe: north carolina
Expect:  north carolina
Observed matches expected: false
```

It would make sense if there were some leftover Â's in there, from encoding issues, but displaying in the browser as UTF-8, both the value from the input (observed) and the value it is being compared against in the array (expected) look identical. Yet they do not match in code. What's going on?

Comment: try `var_dump()` check string length, might contain a leading whitespace

Comment: I'm running php 5.4, you can do func($array)['element_key']

Comment: It's not supposed to be. I only flip it so that you can see the name of the associative array _key_. `array_flip` returns an array with keys and values flipped, so by typing in the value, you can see the key, the same way by typing in the key, you can see the value in an unflipped array.

Comment: you're right. might help if you can var_dump the entire `$states` list to see

Comment: 50 states, each with a key and value, one opening line, one closing line. That's 102 lines of var_dump. Can't exactly fit that here. They're all the expected length and type though.

Comment: What it gives in vardump after flipping an array.?? $states...

Comment: Here are a few lines of `var_dump()` for `array_keys()` of $states, with the new lines between the `=>` and the type removed for readibility:`[26]=> string(8) "nebraska"` 
`[27]=> string(6) "nevada"` 
`[28]=> string(13) "new hampshire"` 
`[29]=> string(10) "new jersey"` 
`[30]=> string(10) "new mexico"` 
`[31]=> string(8) "new york"` 
`[32]=> string(14) "north carolina"` 
`[33]=> string(12) "north dakota"` 
`[34]=> string(4) "ohio"`

Comment: Does it have trouble only with any states having spaces in them? or just north carolina? or all states?

Comment: `var_dump($s)` please.

Comment: @JeffClayton, good call. Try doing this to `$s` and the flipped value.

Comment: It may be worth your while to string replace spaces to underscores, and trim() the text values before comparison.

Comment: It seems to only be those with spaces